# How do I fix a mount that is now failing

Tags: mount, hard-drive

One of my drives that used to mount, no longer mounts and if possible, I would like to get my data from the drive as that is where my java projects and other things are.

My current /etc/fstab looks like:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=3327438c-aa5e-400f-82d1-f45e1797209c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=ffc7c03a-f85b-477f-8f97-a9879e021783 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

My /etc/mtab looks like:

```
/dev/sdc1 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /run/user tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/gccrowd/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,user=gccrowd 0 0
/dev/sdb2 /media/gccrowd/New\040Volume fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /media/gccrowd/New\040Volume1 fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sdd1 /media/gccrowd/E070DBA970DB84A6 fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sdd7 /media/gccrowd/94B4C1D7B4C1BBCC fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sdd5 /media/gccrowd/8EE8EA51E8EA36DD fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096 0 0
```

The message I get is as follows:

[image]

System information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux brksfwr-desktop 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:31:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The file system is NTFS, so have you done what the message tells you to, i.e. "...run chkdsk /n on Windows, then reboot into Windows twice"?

Comment: It's Ubuntu, so how do I run it on Windows when I have no windows systems to run it on.  It's an internally mounted drive, not an external drive.

Comment: Not much we can help you with. NTFS is a Windows file system, and you need Wndows to fix its errors. Pull out the HDD, and get hold of a Windows box.

Comment: If I had a windows box I could do that, but I don't.  That helps me not at all.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am not a magician, just a fellow Ubuntu user, but, perhaps others will have better ideas. Lets wait and see.

Comment: I put the drive in a drive enclosure and loaded winbloze on my Ubuntu laptop and it sees only an E: drive, even though there are 4 partitions that are NTFS.  And it thinks that the E: drive is empty and needs to be formatted.  So something has only happened to one partition.  If I connect that same external drive to my Ubuntu desktop, it sees 4 partitions but the one partition still will not mount.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I installed GParted and just reformatted that one partition that was causing a problem.  The rest of the partitions were fine.  Now I can use that partition with no problems.  It is not a perfect solution, but I had all the code backed up anyway.

Lesson I learnt, back up frequently.